# Relationship to uxexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, question, scope, definition

What's the plan for how this site will relate to [UX Exchange](http://uxexchange.com/)?

This was brought up by ChrisF on [the Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728?phase=definition), but I'm not sure there was a consensus there. In particular, are the scopes of the two sites the same? If so, having the community split in two places seems like a bad thing.

Answer (score 10):

If the stackexchange site had been named UX instead of UI, I just would have switched and left UXExchange.com even though I have a ton of reputation points there.  However, UI is more limited and so I am torn.  I don't want to deal with two different systems though.

In my perfect world, UXExchange migrates to SE2 and merges with this site and they change the URL to UX instead of UI.  (I can dream, can't I?)

Comment: Couldn't have put it better myself. I'd like to see exactly the same outcome and I hope that the talent currently residing on UXExchange would make the switch too. As it stands, I'm probably going to stick with UXExchange until this is resolved, as I like the wider scope.

Comment: Just tag [ui] all questions from UI.StackExchange! +1 to this alternative.

Comment: The name will change; ui.stackexchange is jut a temporary name for the beta: http://meta.ui.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-name-be

Comment: I agree to your perfect world :) It is confusing since UX is much broader than UI and many in the business of doing UI have realized that it is to limiting, that the experience as a whole not just the interface in itself is what is important.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that the topics are closely related.  I would say that UX is a broader scope and that the UI is really just one part of the user experience as a whole.

So I guess the question is whether or not User Interface would contain content that isn't appropriate for uxexchange.

My answer would be no.  Both sites are geared toward Usability/Accessibility/HCI and while UXExchange has a broader scope, those topics can also be applied to User Interfaces.

Comment: I didn't knw UXExchange, but now it seems like this site is actually redundant :S

Comment: +1 Agree.  UI is a part of UX.  However, I would NOT say information architecture, training techniques, support techniques, graphic design, personas, etc etc are all clearly UI.

Comment: Hear hear Glen! It is also important to educate those coming to do UI work and are new the clear message that UI is more than just the UI. That is an artifact in itself. UX is not an artifact it is a field and the understanding of many of the subjects that Glen Lipka lists will result in a better UI. I would say that the UI is more of a result and UX is the process ... almost.

Answer (score 3):

I think the test will come when, or indeed if, UX Exchange migrates to SE 2.0.

I think that there are two possibilities (NOTE I'm not trying to put words into people's mouths or tell anyone what to do):

a) They decide not to migrate but just direct traffic to this site. This might then have the effect of shifting the focus of this site slightly - which wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing but would have to be treated with caution.

b) They migrate to a new SE 2.0 site at which point there might be a battle for visitors - the outcome of which could be that neither site survives.

There are other sites that have significant overlap with each other so seeing how they fare may well have some bearing on what happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if it's decided that both sites have too similar of a focus, SE2.0 won't allow both of them to exist. UX Exchange was given a 12 month "extension" where they can stay on the platform, at which point they will either have to have enough traction to be moved to 2.0 or they will have to switch to a new platform.

Comment: It's not just about going to SE2 though. UI is limiting and many people do actually work as UX professionals, which is broader.