# Is the merge really complete?

Tags: discussion, merge

> **See update here:**
>   [Rebranding UI to UX + UX Exchange](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/rebranding-ui-to-ux-ux-exchange)

I don't really see how this is status-completed. It doesn't look like the mapping of UXExchange users to UI.SE users took place at all. Is this still in process or what?

Look at this question: [Are "print" links needed on a website?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/are-print-links-needed-on-a-website) I know my accounts matched exactly, and I'm sure that Glen's accounts matched as well. I'm sure there are others too, but I can't find a single merged question where the user accounts match up to an existing SE account.

**UPDATE** The note at the top that says the merge is in progress is gone, but the merged questions still don't appear to be linked and reps still don't appear to be recalculated. Can we get a status update from someone at SE?

Comment: It doesn't look like the global reputation recalc has happened either. I'm guessing they're still working on the account migration.

Comment: Agreed - looks like a work in progress. At least, I hope it's still in progress as the rep is wrong.

Comment: Yes, work is still in progress.

Comment: @Geoff - can we get a status update?

Comment: I'm finding this disappointing and over-whelming, so I think I'm just done.  I'll lurk occasionally to read answers, so I doubt anyone will notice a diff  :)

Comment: @CharlesBoyung, http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/249/post-merge-question-links/254#254

Comment: @SusanR, what is disappointing and overwhelming?

Comment: @Rebecca - I saw that. Doesn't look like the recalc has taken place yet, though.

Comment: @Rebecca - I can't find some things.  Not a reflection on this site, there's lots of great content here. With the merger I'm finding it harder to locate things, and I'm daunted because I can't figure out if it's because of: tags that didn't match, lack of votes, too much info/scope in one place, or my lack of good search techniques for 2.0

Comment: @SusanR, feel free to post a meta question if you're trying to figure out how to do something, or pop into chat (link at the top of the page) and ask.

Answer (score 1):

So - will there be an announcement of when the merge is considered complete?

A system notice or a new thread proclaiming "MISSION ACCOMPLISHED" (or something more realistic and professional) would be useful because **then** we will know if we should keep moaning about missing rep points etc.

Answer (score 0):

We just fixed up some of the missing post owners.

Of the 1361 posts that we migrated, we were able to associate 615 of them with their proper owners on http://ux.stackexchange.com.

**Edit**
I also fixed your 23 posts that were migrated - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Some of my points are back...still missing thousands.  Not sure, Ive lost track.