# Merge with uxexchange.com did not work for me

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ux

> **See update here:**
>   [Rebranding UI to UX + UX Exchange](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/rebranding-ui-to-ux-ux-exchange)

*I didn't get any answer by email and I'm not able to comment or answer anything because I don't have any points.*

So my problem is: I have the same user here as I had on uxexchange.com (logged in with Google ID, so my data is identical). One question got ported and I have 2 badges. But I didn't get any rep. points. Quite a frustrating experience to be honest.

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks, Phil

PS: Also, why is it that only one question got ported? I had asked several and one got >1k views.

**UPDATE**: Jarrod says the migration is done now and everybody should have their rep back. Well, I still don't have any points from uxexchange.com (the 86 I have now are all from here). So yeah, back to building rep... anyway, great community. I'll definitely stick around :)

**UPDATE 2**: Ok, just saw that not all the 86 rep are from here, so some got ported. Still about 400-something missing.

Comment: Voted to migrate to meta, but in the meantime see http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/240/rebranding-ui-to-ux-ux-exchange

Comment: To answer the rep point, if the accounts that voted *for* you didn't get merged then you probably won't get the rep from those votes. Or the rep recalc hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Didn't know about the meta page, would have posted it there. Rep: Seems to me that the recalc happend already. So I gotta start from scratch, can't even upvote... argh.

Comment: I can fix the ownership.  Let me dig up your posts.

Comment: Yey, thanks for the upvote, now I can comment at least :) @Rebecca: Thanks, that'd be great. Just wondering: Why is my profile on meta.ux. not exactly the same as on ux.? (e.g. I can't add an openID)

Comment: @Rebecca Can we have a status update on the account merging and recalc? Is it still a work in progress? Please let us know either way.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same experience: 1200 rep points have vanished

(So I can currently answer - but not comment !)

:-(

Comment: UPDATE: I now have more (all) my rep points - and enough to function.  It looks like there's an 'exchange rate' between the two sites of about 4 UX Exchange Rep Points = 1 User Experience Rep Point.

Comment: Not all of the questions were migrated, so if some your rep came from posts that were left behind you won't regain that rep, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

<del>I don't think the merge is quite complete yet. Or there are kinks yet to work out.</del>

It looks like the calculations are correct now. Not all of the rep from uxexchange.com was carried over.

- Only a subset of questions were migrated.
- Questions are now awarded 5 rep per upvote. (I think the old site was still 10.)
- There's an off chance you hit the cap of 200 rep / day on a day in which you earned rep on both sites.

Answer (score 2):

We finished fixing a few things that went wrong during the mass-migration.  All the up/down votes are properly transfered, so your rep is correct now.

Comment: Hi Jarrod - well, I didn't get any rep from uxexchange.com (had something around 500). The ones I have now are all from here... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I know the feeling - just over 1000 rep points missing. I believe the checklist was - same user name, same email address, same openid. I checked all those pre-merge and updated the openid, so as far as I know everything was okay and should have migrated.

Comment: Same here. Well, I guess we've got to start building rep again over here.

Comment: It's sad to be disreputable (again). :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite confused.

On the new site I have 101 rep, i.e. brand new linked account. But all of my questions and up-voted answers show up in my profile. How do those go together?

I also already had rep here, as well as at the old site. Merging, I would think, would combine these, but I seem to have ended up with neither.

Answer (score 1):

4000+ points missing.  Sme showed up.  Not many of tem. :(

Comment: See Charles's answer. You should have a lot more rep coming once they get it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, some of my points just showed up - all with a date happening of 3/31. But they are points from many different posts, all much older (some going back to 2009). It hit the cap for that day, so I'm not sure what's going to happen with everything else. Are we all going to be limited to 200 points moved over from the other site? Doesn't seem to make a lot of sense that way.

Comment: I noticed the same thing on your account and a couple others. I guess they're still having trouble getting the merge and recalc to work right.

Comment: This has been fixed - was an issue with how the votes were moved.  The first time something is done tends to have a few quirks :)