# When will the recalc occur?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, merge

> **See update here:**
>   [Rebranding UI to UX + UX Exchange](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/rebranding-ui-to-ux-ux-exchange)

See [Merge with uxexchange.com did not work for me](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/ot-merge-with-uxexchange-com-did-not-work-for-me)

The recalc has not occurred yet and people that came over from UXExchange are starting to get frustrated with not being able to do much (since they don't have many points over here yet). Can we get an update on when the recalc will occur?

Comment: I think the recalc has occurred. For some reason rep from imported questions isn't factoring into the calculation. (I just did a manual recalc on your account and nothing changed.)

Comment: @Patrick - Okay, then that's a bigger problem. The imported questions were supposed to be included, weren't they? I thought that was the whole reason to do the recalc post-merge.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. I think the SE team is focused on an [even bigger problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85884/add-comment-flag-delete-links-are-broken) at the moment, but I'm hoping to hear something from them by the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Everything has been fixed - your rep totals should now be correct.

Comment: Wow, so only about 600 of 2000+ of my rep moved over. Were there really that many questions that didn't get merged?

Comment: @CharlesBoyung, we calculated a score for each question, based on a couple metrics.  We sorted by that and went down until we felt quality was starting to slip, and took the "best-of" from the top of that list.

Comment: @Rebecca - I understand that - I think you just went a little far with where you felt quality was starting to slip. There weren't THAT many lower quality questions.